# Why v-on:click="method()" is treat as a method declaration like the v-on:click="method"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Consider this example https://codesandbox.io/s/1yvp4zz5x7?module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button v-on:click="method">Greet1</button>
    <button v-on:click="method()">Greet2</button>
  </div>  
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      method() {
        alert('Hello');
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Both buttons will work exactly the same (I'm aware of passing event in the first example) despite the fact that in `v-on:click` in "Greet1" there is **method declaration** and in "Greet2" there is **method invokation**.

Shouldn't "Greet2" display alert during component rendering phase and this button shouldn't work on clicking since I didn't return function in `method()`?

Why there is this mechanism here and how it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is not called immediately, because before the template is ever rendered, it is compiled into a function. During the compilation process, the `v-on` click expression is parsed by Vue and handled in two separate ways. Essentially, what happens when the template is compiled in the case of

```
<button v-on:click="method">Greet1</button>
```

is that the click handler is set directly to `method`. In the case of

```
<button v-on:click="method()">Greet2</button>
```

the click handler is set to

```
function($event) { method() }
```

The entire compiled render function is wrapped in a `with(this)` so that `method()` and other things that are declared that way are resolved properly.

Here is a little snippet [from the generated code](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js) that shows how this is decided.

```
var fnExpRE = /^\s*([\w$_]+|\([^)]*?\))\s*=>|^function\s*\(/;
var simplePathRE = /^\s*[A-Za-z_$][\w$]*(?:\.[A-Za-z_$][\w$]*|\['.*?']|\[".*?"]|\[\d+]|\[[A-Za-z_$][\w$]*])*\s*$/;

...many lines omitted...

var isMethodPath = simplePathRE.test(handler.value);
var isFunctionExpression = fnExpRE.test(handler.value);

if (!handler.modifiers) {
  if (isMethodPath || isFunctionExpression) {
    return handler.value
  }

  return ("function($event){" + (handler.value) + "}") // inline statement
}
```

If you read through the code of the above link, the function in question is `genHandler` (for this particular version of Vue, which is 2.5.13).

Comment: Disclaimer: Vue is among my top favorite libraries to work with. The fact that both of these do the same thing does feel like kind of a fault with Vue's templating system in terms of consistency. Maybe I want to have a function which returns a function to use as a handler, e.g. `@click="createClickHandler()"`, would it just call `createClickHandler()` without using the actual handler returned from it?

Comment: @kingdaro My expectation is that Vue would call createClickHandler and not the function returned from it. But I'll test and check it out! One thing I will mention is that using a template isn't mandatory; you can always write your own render function. It's not hard really.

Comment: @kingdaro Here is the [little experiment snippet](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/ejgQoK?editors=1010). As expected, `createClickHandler` will be called as the function. Also as @everettss suggests, there is an easy (though maybe non-intuitive) way around it.

Comment: I figured as such, which I guess is fine since the scenario I proposed isn't all too common. Still, I'm thinking it might be better for vue in the future to always use the `method()` form for less ambiguity. I hear there's an update coming soon (next few months, maybe?) and I wonder if this is something they've thought about

Comment: You totally nailed **"how it works?"**. As turn's out there is a problem with the question **"why?"**. I suppose this lack of consistency is a side effect of "magic" in vue templating system.

Comment: @Everettss I can only speculate as to the why. I expect it's primarily for flexibility. In the case of an inline handler, there are cases where you may want to pass a number of parameters to a handler. Or, possibly you might want to use a function factory as described in discussion above; in those cases you would need the inline handler syntax. However, for ease of use, when all you want is for the handler to call one of your methods, just specifying the method is nice. In my own code, the only time I would really use the inline syntax `method()` is when I **intend** to pass parameters.

Comment: @kingdaro "_it might be better for vue in the future to always use the `method()` form_": considering this would not be backwards compatible, it would require a major version change. I feel this is very unlikely then. My other 2 cents: while it can indeed be seen as ambiguous, the docs clearly mention the 2 forms; and I feel the key here is indeed _flexibility_, and maybe even more importantly, tolerance to newbie mistake. By accepting the 2 forms with similar behaviour, Vue is easier to learn for a JS newcomer.

Comment: Well, I'd rather have a template system with less surprises and special cases than one that's "nice", personally, but it is a case-by-case thing. They do document this well enough